# open many forms in a panel by link labels in desktop application in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

My problem is  ..I am able to add form in panel BY.

```
 Form2 fm2 = new Form2();
 fm2.TopLevel = false;
 fm2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
 panel1.Controls.Add(fm2);
 fm2.Show();
```

but when i try to  remove form  from panel. By

```
panel1.Controls.Remove(fm2);
```

Nothing workss.This code note  remove FORM from panel..

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code should work even without closing form explicitely. Make sure `fm2` points to form which you have added:

```
Form2 fm2 = panel1.Controls.OfType<Form2>().First();
panel1.Controls.Remove(fm2);
```

UPDATE: Again, you should remove exactly same *instance* of Form2 which you have added to panel. Creating new instance and removing it from panel does nothing, because that new instance was not added to panel and original instance still exist in panel.

I suggest you to remove all controls from panel, if you just want to use it as host to your forms. Just call `panel1.Controls.Clear()`.

Comment: i am using this frm2.close(); and also frm2.dispose but nothing happen :( @Sergey Berezovkiy

Comment: @DaniDanish updated answer, I think you are removing wrong control

Comment: @DaniDanish so, have verified what `fm2` you have? Have you tried solution above?

Comment: frmAddStudent addStd = new frmAddStudent();
            panel2.Controls.Remove(addStd);
            addStd.Close();
            addStd.Dispose();

            frmAddFines addfine = new frmAddFines();
            addfine.TopLevel = false;
            panel2.Controls.Add(addfine);
            addfine.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            addfine.Show();

Comment: this the real code but the form frmAddStudent is not closing in the panel

Comment: are you understanding my problem or not @Sergey Berezovskiy

Comment: @DaniDanish I do understand your problem. You are creating new instance of `frmAddStudent` which not exist in `panel2`. Then you are trying to remove that new form instance from `panel2` controls. Which of course does not remove instance of `frmAddStudent` which you have added to `panel2`

Comment: i am calling first that instance then this another likn label is clicked after that instance

Comment: @DaniDanish I don't know how to explain it to you. `frmAddStudent addStd = new frmAddStudent();` creates brand new instance of `frmAddStudent` form. That instance does not exist in any `Controls` collection. You have another `frmAddStudent` instance on panel. Not this. See my update

Comment: i got an idea ... i am globally defining the all the forms then romove and adding controls ... i think this approach is very better in my case ... thanks my friend for you responce @Sergey Berezovskiy

Comment: instead of this i m using frm.Dispose(); @Sergey Berezovskiy

Answer (score 0):

You could try to close form before remove it from Panel:

```
fm2.Close(); //Or fm2.Visible = false;
panel1.Controls.Remove(fm2);
```